# What are integer matrices and examples

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Can some one explain to me what are integer matrices and can you guys give an 
example of two 2 x 2 integer matrices that commute when multiplied.

Comment: Diagonal matrices are a trivial example of commuting matrices. So are powers of a given matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but just one question how do u multiply the matrices in order to get the answer?? is it a diagonal multiplication ?? could give me a step by step example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer matrix is a matrix whose entries are integers. Take for example

$$
I=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right].
$$

and

$$
K=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$

Then $IK=KI$.

**Edit**: To address your follow-up question, I found the two matrices by intuition. To show that they are commutative, I just calculated $IK$ and $KI$ by the definition of matrix multiplication.

If you want a more constructive approach, let $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{array}\right]$ be integer matrices. Note that 
$$
AB=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}\\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
BA=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
b_{11}a_{11}+b_{12}a_{21} & b_{11}a_{12}+b_{12}a_{22}\\
b_{21}a_{11}+b_{22}a_{21} & b_{21}a_{12}+b_{22}a_{22}
\end{array}\right].
$$
Equating $AB=BA$ yields the four equations
\begin{align*}
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21} & =b_{11}a_{11}+b_{12}a_{21}\\
a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22} & =b_{11}a_{12}+b_{12}a_{22}\\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21} & =b_{21}a_{11}+b_{22}a_{21}\\
a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22} & =b_{21}a_{12}+b_{22}a_{22}.
\end{align*}
You should be able to convince yourself that this system is underdetermined
(i.e. infinitely many solutions, one of which is $A=I$ and $B=K$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer... please tell me the process of finding the product of this matricie.

Comment: and how u can prove or disprove it, the process.

Comment: Hey thanks for the followup !! I am truly grateful . Just one last question:

So by seeing the process and looking at the conclusion... then can I sat that the matrix product of any two 2x2 integer matrices is commutative? because its infinite?

Comment: @Martin : Some matrices do not commute. For instance, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
are matrices that do not commute. All you can conclude from the fact that there are infinitely many solutions of this system is that there exists non-commuting matrices, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Friend !! That was some prompt response and great help !

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the help bud.. that was the answer I was looking for .

Answer (score 2):

Integer matrices are just matrices whose coefficients are integers.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Hope that helps,

Comment: okay thanks for the answer... just one question how do u multiply the matricies in order to get the answer (1 0 1 1) ?

Comment: and how can you prove or disprove it, the process. Please.

Comment: @Martin : There is nothing to prove, I simply computed both products! If you know how to multiply matrices, you can see that I am correct. If you are asking how I came up with these examples, that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

An integer matrix is a matrix with integer entries. Here is an example:
$$
\pmatrix{ 3 & 2 \\ 7 & 5}
$$
This matrix commutes with
$$
\pmatrix{ \hphantom{-}5 & -2 \\ -7 & \hphantom{-}3}
$$
(and the product is the identity matrix)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but just one question how do u multiply the matrices in order to get the answer?? is it a diagonal multiplication ??

Comment: and how can you prove or disprove it, the process. Thanks you

Comment: @Martin, see [Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).